# Checking the AsyncTask status seems not working correctly (log doesn't appear on log cat)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to see how works an Asynctask class in android. In particular i want reveal in real time the status of the class for see when it is running and when it has finished. For do this, i have created a class that extend the main activity and another class that is the asynctaks class.
This is my main class:

```
public class PhotoManagement extends Activity{
private String numberOfSelectedPhotos;
private Bitmap currentImage;
private String initConfiguration = "http://www.something.com";
private String response;
private ArrayList<String> formatPhotoList = new ArrayList<String>(); //create a list that will contains the available format of the photos downloaded from the server
private ArrayList<String> pricePhotoList = new ArrayList<String>(); //create a list that will contains the available price for each format of the photos
DownloadWebPageTask webPage = new DownloadWebPageTask();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    webPage.execute(initConfiguration);
    if(webPage.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){   
        Log.i("STATUS","PENDING");
    }
    if(webPage.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
        Log.i("","RUNNING");
    }
    if(webPage.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        Log.i("","FINISHED");
    }
}
}
```

As you can see i want only see the passages of the status with a simple log.
And here there is the asynctask class.

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); //create a new http client
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); //create a new http request passing a valid url
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet); //try to execute the http get request
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent(); //prepare the input stream to read the bytes of the request
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s; //until is present a line to read, the response variable store the value of the lines
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("MyApp", "Download Exception : " + e.toString()); //Print the error if something goes wrong
            }
        }
        return response; //return the response
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        result = doInBackground(initConfiguration); //take the result from the DownloadWebPageTask class
        result = result.replace("null", "");
        Log.i("RESULT",""+result);
        //find the price and format value from the result using XmlPullParser
        try {
           XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
           factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( result ) );
            int attributeNumber = xpp.getAttributeCount();
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            String currentTag = null;
            while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    currentTag = xpp.getName();
                    if (currentTag.equals("product")){
                        xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                        formatPhotoList.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        Log.i("FORMAT PHOTO",""+xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                    }
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("","ERROR XML PULL PARSER");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("","ERROR IOEXCEPTION");
        }
    }

}   
}
```

As you can see i have implemented also the method onPostExecute that should be called when the asynctask method has finished to execute the instructions right?
So at this point i don't understand why my log RUNNING and my log FINISHED never appear on the log cat.
What i'm doing wrong?
I'm tried to follow this topic [Android, AsyncTask, check status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588584/android-asynctask-check-status) but in my case it isn't working.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Problem :**

You are creating object like

```
DownloadWebPageTask webPage = new DownloadWebPageTask();
```

But you are calling asynctask on different object,

```
new DownloadWebPageTask().execute(initConfiguration);
```

**Solution :**
It should be like

```
webPage.execute(initConfiguration);
```

Comment: thanks. As you can see i have updated my code. Now it log correctly the running status, but it doesn't log the finished status. Shouldn't he return the finished status automatically?

Comment: result = doInBackground(initConfiguration); what is this line doing?

Comment: this line assign the result of the doInBackground method to the variable "result". In fact after as you can see, i work with this variable.

Comment: no need to use that, you are already getting it in 
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

Comment: you are right thanks. Any idea of why the method never show the "FINISHED" log? I have tested it now but nothing change...

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    new DownloadWebPageTask().execute(initConfiguration);
```

here do like this

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    webPage.execute(initConfiguration);
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I have updated my code. Now it enter correctly on the running status, but it doesn't show the finished status. Shouldn't he return the finished status automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't implement `webPage.execute()`, add it

Comment: yes thanks. I have fixed my code now, but i'm not receiving the status "finished" in any way. Now i can see correctly the "running" status, so my problem isn't fixed yet thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the task hasn't finished or even started yet. As you probably know the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is doing it's (background) work on a different thread, so your `onResume` is running in parallel with it. You can either use the task's [get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method to wait for it to finish and get the result of the `doInBackground()` method and then query for it's status or notify your activity from the task's `onPostExecute()` method to let it know (and log) that it has finished. I don't recommend you the first option because it will actually block the UI thread and will make your usage of AsyncTask pointless.