# Run multiple Asynctask one after another when a condition is satisfied

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have multiple asynctasks in my application, I want to execute it when a specific condition is satisfied. For example,

class Task1 extends AsyncTask...

class Task2 extends AsyncTask..

class Task3 extends AsyncTask...

I have a while loop which is used to iterate some values from a map.
eg:

```
while(iterator.next())

{

 Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();

            String title = pair.getKey().toString();

if(title.equals("one"))

{

//execute task1;

}else if(title.equals("two"))

{

//execute task2;

}

etc..
}
```

This is a sample code i currently used.
Each Task contains a progress dialog, which is starting on onPreExcecute() and 
dismissed on onPostExecute().

My Problem is that I want to execute only one task at a time. 
In my code all tasks are started at same time and progress dialog will overlap each other. So there is any way to  execute only one task at a time,
Thanks is advance.

Comment: try to create in one asynch task

Comment: start with one Asynctask call the next one on onPostExecute.

Comment: keep a queue of tasks, when the first ends it calls the next one in postExe

Comment: Thanks for replay, but i can not call Asynctask from onPostExecute, because i have a hash map with a list of strings, based on that strings , i want to execute tasks. So i don't want to execute all the task.

Comment: You can test condition in each onPostExecute , can't you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is while loop. The loop will continue to run even if a task is running in background. So you must modify your code such a way  that the loop condition is triggered only if one task is completed.

To handle the progressbar issue, create a global progressbar object which can be shared by all the asyncTasks.

Refer the following link for checking status of AsynTasks.
[AsynTask Status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7588655/1611938)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that overlap the progressDialog is running the multipple asnyntask .
so you start first asyntask and the call next form its postExcecutive.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstanding of `AsyncTask`. The default executor of AsyncTask is a serial executor, which means that it will executes tasks **one at a time in serial order** in a particular process. But why the process dialogs are shown at a time? After you read the code of `AsyncTask`, you can find the reason in function executeOnExecutor:

```
public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> executeOnExecutor(Executor exec,
            Params... params) {
    mStatus = Status.RUNNING;
    onPreExecute();
    mWorker.mParams = params;
    exec.execute(mFuture);
    return this;
}
```

You can find that method `onPreExecute` is called before execute, ie it is not serial called. So the progress dialogs are appearing at the same time.

I think you can modify your code by using only one progress dialog in your main activity and show or hide the dialog by its status.